# Get Cell Content in one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get my cell content in excel worksheet to another worksheet by using a user defined function. So I searched stackoverflow and found the following vba code.

```
Function GetValue(sheetName As String, cellAddress As String) As Variant
   GetSheetValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Range(cellAddress)
End Function
```

This is the right thing i expected.But it doesn't work for me. I need to develop a user defined function as like follows.

```
=GetContent(Sheet1,B6)
```

I've tried many things but I can't do it. So I'm very appriciate any responses about this matter. (Provide Screenshots about my example)

Thank You
[ScreenShot 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wexm6.png)
[ScreenShot 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPLOC.png)

Comment: I will assume this is for practice.  `=GetContent("Sheet1","B6")` since strings are required, they must be in quotes.  but `=Sheet1!B6` does it now without vba.

Comment: Also make sure the code is in a module attached to the workbook and not worksheet or ThisWorbook code.

Comment: @ScottCraner not an issue with the strings being typed without quotes (vba will convert them to the string type since its specified in the function).  Look carefully in the screenshot and you'll see OP didn't capitalize, so the sheet wasn't found

Comment: @RGA that would be true if the OP was referencing cells that contained the strings. But as he/she is typing them directly in the formula it must have the quotes. Otherwise how is excel to know that the B6 is the reference and not the contents in B6 on that page.

Comment: @ScottCraner ahh I missed that.  Good spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. My function must be correct as following code.

```
Function GetContent(sheetName As String, cellAddress As String) As String
    GetContent = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Range(cellAddress)
End Function
```

I didn't concern abot the function name and return as the same. But we have to must do it. Also in string data type we have use quotaions and Case sensitive. So thanks all of you for valuable help. It helps me to fid out the answer. Now wecan use the functions as follows.

```
=GetContent("Sheet2","b5")
```

Thank You!